# Joomla Blank template issues

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, menu, width

I'm creating my own Joomla template and I've ran into some problem's.

I'm using blank template and am fallowing this tutorial: [Blank Joomla template with Bootstrap](http://blank.vc/blog/6-blank-template-and-twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-for-joomla.html)

### So the issue:

*The original question is:*
if I have 2 modules (span3 and span 9) and if he wants when he disappears "span3" span9 take the whole width, is it possible?

*The answer by the author of the tutorial*:
It is possible though php with short if-else-statement:

```
echo ($this->countModules( 'sidebar' )) ? ('span9') : ('span12');
```

My question: 
Where I should put this "simple" code to achieve the result needed?

---

In case it would help, here is how the script's are loaded in the header:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/js/template.js.php"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Super User" />
  <meta name="description" content="Turdi Designs Descripcion" />
  <title>eBay</title>
  <link href="http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=2&amp;Itemid=466" rel="canonical" />
  <link href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/css/template.css.php?v=1.0.0" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
  </script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" /> <!-- mobile viewport -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/css/tablet.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/css/phone.css" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IEMobile]><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/css/phone.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]--> <!-- iemobile -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"> <!-- iphone, ipod, android -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"> <!-- ipad -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"> <!-- iphone retina -->
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <style> 
      {behavior:url(/joomla/templates/turdi_designs/js/PIE.htc);}
    </style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I depends what you are going to do on the basis of this. If you are going to include js or something then sure you would want to do some of this in the header and then do more in the index.php.
However, if you are only going to render the boot strap row, put it right where you want the row to be. Basically this is just a conditional include so include it where you need it.

Look in either Protostar or Beez to see examples of this.